# Program received signal: "0"

Tags: signals

I am getting following error on my application:

```
Program received signal:"0".
Data Formatters temporarily unavaliable, will re-try after a "continue". (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib'libXcodeDebuggerSuppot.dylib").
```

Above words appeared when I ran the application on a I-pad connecting with the computer. 
Would you please tell me the reason and how to resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program received signal: "0". No prior sign of trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511213/program-received-signal-0-no-prior-sign-of-trouble)

Answer (score 1):

This normally means you are using too much memory.  iPhone will terminate your application once it has gone out of bounds.  (signal 0).  Verify that you are properly handling your memory allocation and deallocation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html